# Jframe dispose on condition

Tags: java, swing, jframe, dispose, thread-sleep

This is my code:

```
public Loading(Evento e){
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.evento = e;
    new Thread(new thread1()).start();
}
public class thread1 implements Runnable{
    @Override
public void run(){
        for (int i=0; i<=100; i++){ //Progressively increment variable i
            jpb.setValue(i); //Set value
            jpb.repaint(); //Refresh graphics
            try{
                Thread.sleep(30);
                if(i==100){
                    GestaoEvento a = new GestaoEvento(evento);
                    a.setVisible(true);
                    --->>>>this.dispose();<<<<---
                }
            } //Sleep 50 milliseconds
            catch (InterruptedException err){}
        }
}
}
```

`this.dispose()` doesn't work there because `this` refers to the thread, how can I close this frame there?

Comment: most of methods in swing are not thread safe, so calling in another thread rather than in the `EDT` perhaps don't work as you expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Related to your question**:
`this` refer to the instance of inner class. You have to use
`Loading.this.dispose()`.

**Most important**

Calling `jpb.repaint();` in another thread that is not the EDT can cause unexpected behaviour, and calling `Thread.sleep(30);` is gonna to freeze your gui. Instead use a `SwingTimer`

Read more: [How to use SwingTimers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) | [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)